# Доступ к модулю и актеру внутри dataProvider-метода (PhpUnit + Codeception)

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit, codeception

Здравствуйте!

Возникла необходимость получить модуль или доступ к актеру в dataProvider-методе. К сожалению, [с 2014 года все никак не пофиксят](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/862), что все инициализации тестов происходят до бутстрапа, в итоге в dataProvider невозможно получить ни актера, ни модули. Мне это необходимо для инициализации модуля (читай хелпера) с методами генерации фейковых данных (и экземпляром Faker-генератора).

Неужели нет никаких вменяемых способов получить желаемое, кроме как использовать трейт с нужными инициализациями и методами или прослойку в виде родительского класса для теста?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в бутстрапе. Аннотацию dataProvider обрабатывает PHPUnit, который ничего не знает о Codeception.

Можно сгенерировать данные в тесте, а затем в цикле отправить их в отдельный метод для проверки:

```
public function testMe()
{
    $one = $this->tester->getData();

    $data = [
        [$one, 2]
    ];

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $this->me($item[0], $item[1]);
    }
}


public function me($a, $b)
{
    $this->assertSame($a, $b);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, данный подход заставляет писать сверху некоторую часть ненужного кода с возможностями нормального вывода ошибок (в стиле тех, кто выдаются при использовании dataProvider). Жаль. Остается выбирать между доступными вариантами самый удобный и не ломающий архитектуру тестов.

Comment: Кроме того, данный код не проверит все дата сеты, а выйдет из теста на первом сломанном ассерте.